# Asynchronous MPI with SysV shared memory

Tags: mpi, shared-memory, fortran90

We have a large Fortran/MPI code-base which makes use of system-V shared memory segments on a node. We run on fat nodes with 32 processors, but only 2 or 4 NICs, and relatively little memory per CPU; so the idea is that we set up a shared memory segment, on which each CPU performs its calculation (in its block of the SMP array). MPI is then used to handle inter-node communications, but only on the master in the SMP group. The procedure is double-buffered, and has worked nicely for us.

The problem came when we decided to switch to asynchronous comms, for a bit of latency hiding.  Since only a couple of CPUs on the node communicate over MPI, but all of the CPUs see the received array (via shared memory), a CPU doesn't know when the communicating CPU has finished, unless we enact some kind of barrier, and then why do asynchronous comms?

The ideal, hypothetical solution would be to put the request tags in an SMP segment and run mpi_request_get_status on the CPU which needs to know. Of course, the request tag is only registered on the communicating CPU, so it doesn't work! Another proposed possibility was to branch a thread off on the communicating thread and use it to run mpi_request_get_status in a loop, with the flag argument in a shared memory segment, so all the other images can see. Unfortunately, that's not an option either, since we are constrained not to use threading libraries.

The only viable option we've come up with seems to work, but feels like a dirty hack. We put an impossible value in the upper-bound address of the receive buffer, that way once the mpi_irecv has completed, the value has changed and hence every CPU knows when it can safely use the buffer. Is that ok? It seems that it would only work reliably if the MPI implementation can be guaranteed to transfer data consecutively. That almost sounds convincing, since we've written this thing in Fortran and so our arrays are contiguous; I would imagine that the access would be also.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Joly

Here's a pseudo-code template of the kind of thing I'm doing. Haven't got the code as a reference at home, so I hope I haven't forgotten anything crucial, but I'll make sure when I'm back to the office...

```
pseudo(array_arg1(:,:), array_arg2(:,:)...)

  integer,      parameter : num_buffers=2
  Complex64bit, smp       : buffer(:,:,num_buffers)
  integer                 : prev_node, next_node
  integer                 : send_tag(num_buffers), recv_tag(num_buffers)
  integer                 : current, next
  integer                 : num_nodes

  boolean                 : do_comms
  boolean,      smp       : safe(num_buffers)
  boolean,      smp       : calc_complete(num_cores_on_node,num_buffers)

  allocate_arrays(...)

  work_out_neighbours(prev_node,next_node)

  am_i_a_slave(do_comms)

  setup_ipc(buffer,...)

  setup_ipc(safe,...)

  setup_ipc(calc_complete,...)

  current = 1
  next = mod(current,num_buffers)+1

  safe=true

  calc_complete=false

  work_out_num_nodes_in_ring(num_nodes)

  do i=1,num_nodes

    if(do_comms)
      check_all_tags_and_set_safe_flags(send_tag, recv_tag, safe) # just in case anything else has finished.
      check_tags_and_wait_if_need_be(current, send_tag, recv_tag)
      safe(current)=true
    else
      wait_until_true(safe(current))
    end if

    calc_complete(my_rank,current)=false
    calc_complete(my_rank,current)=calculate_stuff(array_arg1,array_arg2..., buffer(current), bounds_on_process)
    if(not calc_complete(my_rank,current)) error("fail!")

    if(do_comms)
      check_all_tags_and_set_safe(send_tag, recv_tag, safe)

      check_tags_and_wait_if_need_be(next, send_tag, recv_tag)
      recv(prev_node, buffer(next), recv_tag(next))
      safe(next)=false

      wait_until_true(all(calc_complete(:,current)))
      check_tags_and_wait_if_need_be(current, send_tag, recv_tag)
      send(next_node, buffer(current), send_tag(current))
      safe(current)=false
    end if

    work_out_new_bounds()

    current=next
    next=mod(next,num_buffers)+1

  end do
end pseudo
```

So ideally, I would have liked to have run "check_all_tags_and_set_safe_flags" in a loop in another thread on the communicating process, or even better: do away with "safe flags" and make the handle to the sends / receives available on the slaves, then I could run: "check_tags_and_wait_if_need_be(current, send_tag, recv_tag)" (mpi_wait) before the calculation on the slaves instead of "wait_until_true(safe(current))".

Comment: Your assumption about the way MPI transfers messages is not correct in genral. Large messages are usually broken into chunks that are then sent independently and may arrive in an arbitrary order (e.g. Open MPI + multiple network interconnects). It only depends on the MPI implementation and not on the language the program is written in. It is bad that you are constrained to not use threading libraries since your problem sounds as a good candidate for hybrid MPI/OpenMP solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"...unless we enact some kind of barrier, and then why do asynchronous comms?"*

That sentence is a bit confused.  The purpose of asynchrononous communications is to overlap communications and computations; that you can hopefully get some real work done while the communications is going on.   But this means you now have two tasks occuring which eventually *have* to be synchronized, so there **has** to be something which blocks the tasks at the end of the first communications phase before they go onto the second computation phase (or whatever).

The question of what to do in this case to implement things nicely (it seems like what you've got now works but you're rightly concerned about the fragility of the result) depends on how you're doing the implementation.    You use the word threads, but (a) you're using sysv shared memory segments, which you wouldn't need to do if you had threads, and (b) you're constrained not to be using threading libraries, so presumably you actually mean you're fork()ing processes after MPI_Init() or something?

I agree with Hristo that your best bet is almost certainly to use OpenMP for on-node distribution of computation, and would probably greatly simplify your code.   It would help to know more about your constraint to not use threading libraries.

Another approach which would still avoid you having to "roll your own" process-based communication layer that you use in addition to MPI would be to have *all* the processes on the node be MPI processes, but create a few communicators - one to do the global communications, and one "local" communicator per node.   Only a couple of processes per node would be a part of a communicator which actually does off-node communications, and the others do work on the shared memory segment.  Then you could use MPI-based methods for synchronization (Wait, or Barrier) for the on-node synchronization.   The upcoming MPI3 will actually have some explicit support for using local shared memory segments this way.

Finally, if you're absolutely bound and determined to keep doing things through what's essentially your own local-node-only IPC implementation --- since you're already using SysV shared memory segments, you might as well use [SysV semaphores](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html) to do the synchronization.   You're already using your own (somewhat delicate) semaphore-like mechanism to "flag" when the data is ready for computation; here you could use a more robust, already-written semaphore to let the non-MPI processes know when the data is ready for computation (and a similar mechanism to let the MPI process know when the others are done with the computation).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that; I appreciate that we will need to wait, even with asynchronous communications. What I was worried about, but expressed poorly was that a process may be ready to switch to a safe buffer, but be waiting for the communicating process to reach the point where it polls the request-tags and informs the slave of the safe state of the buffer; a kind of second-order waiting, not merely waiting for the comms to finish.

Comment: I guess I should clarify the threads situation; we aren't using any threading library or doing process forking at the moment, just pure MPI with SysV on a node. I mentioned it only because I think that threading is the way to go, despite the fact that I can't for the following reasons. OpenMP ought to be ideal, but unfortunately to use it effectively we would need to rework significant portions of the code, and the other developers aren't willing for it to be used sporadically, just for spawning an MPI-request-tag polling thread, or (more sensibly) even using OpenMP to handle the

Comment: shared memory / the loop directly. The reason given was that OpenMP is apparently slow to branch threads, so either someone rewrites the underlying comms architecture with OpenMP above MPI in the heirarchy, or we aren't willing to pay the latency cost. Posix threads was another option, but we are (unfortunately) bound to support Microsoft Windows, where the Unix subsystem is optional and may be going away with Windows 8. Overall, I don't think I'll be able to win the threading library argument with the developers.

Comment: Effectively, all I wanted was another thread on the communicating process to poll the request tags, or a way to pass those request tags to the other processes in a way which allows me to poll them on those processes. I think I may have over-estimated the problem and perhaps by polling the request-tags at several points in the loop serially, and informing the slave processes by whatever means, there may be little problem. It just seemed like there might be a more elegant solution. You mention process forking, but I was under the impression that it was strongly discouraged in MPI?

Comment: If that's an option, it's conceivable that I could extend my shared memory segment to the new process and perhaps do the calculation phase in it, but my instinct says that's going to be complicated and expensive.

Comment: So, at the moment, I have essentially what you outlined in your fourth paragraph. In the code there are several layers of MPI parallelism, each with its own communicator, the lowest level of which is split into an inter-node and intra-node communicator. There was no need to set up another sub-communicator however, since I am working on a purely systolic algorithm. Those processes which are set up to communicate, do their point to point comms with their adjacent processes in the inter-node communicator (send/recving the entire SMP segment) and those which aren't, skip the comms phase entirely.

Comment: "The reason given was that OpenMP is apparently slow to branch threads" -- as opposed to all the overhead with the processes and SysV stuff?  I suspect that's just another way of them saying "...because we don't want to."

Comment: All processes however, always do the calculation phase on their section of the SMP segment. I still run into the problem though, that I can't do an MPI_wait on the slave processes because only the communicating process has the request tag. It was also very useful to have you mention semaphores. I had a look through our IPC module and there are routines for doing exactly what you describe on the shared memory segment.

Comment: So I think, with the aid of yourself and Dr. Iliev I'm beginning to piece a solution together. The communicating node needs to poll its request tags often in the loop, or even better in a forked process if that's cheap and easy; this then sets the semaphores on the buffer appropriately for the slave processes to deal with. I just wish there were a way to run an mpi_wait on a request tag of another process.

Comment: Comments are for small comments; updates to questions go in edits to the answers.   I agree it's sometimes awkward.   Note I'm not _recommending_ forking, I'm asking if that's what you're doing.  I'm afraid I still don't understand what your code is actually doing at the moment, perhaps editing your question with some pseudocode would help.